# Dockerfile can't run shell scripts inside Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a shell script file inside a docker container. It's working as expected when testing it with the command line but not when running it inside Jenkins.

This is my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get dist-upgrade -y \
 && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential libgtest-dev \
 && apt-get clean

WORKDIR /src

COPY . .

#working when using CLI and Jenkinsfile
RUN echo "test" 

#working when using CLI and Jenkinsfile
RUN ls 

#working when using CLI but NOT with Jenkinsfile
RUN ./build.sh 

CMD ["./run_tests.sh"]
```

And this is how I run the dockerfile:

**docker-build.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x

#stop and rm old container if any
docker container stop build-fw
docker container rm build-fw

docker build -t build-fw .

docker run --name build-fw -d -it build-fw

docker logs build-fw

docker container stop build-fw
docker container rm build-fw
```

In Jenkins, I simply created a Freestyle project with the "Execute Shell" build step, where I simply ran the "docker-build.sh" script:

**Execute Shell**

```
./docker-build.sh
```

I got the following error output:

```
#12 0.586 /bin/sh: 1: ./build.sh: not found
#12 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ./build.sh]: exit code: 127
------
 > [8/8] RUN build.sh:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ./build.sh]: exit code: 127
```

The error states, that `./build.sh` was not found, although `RUN ls` shows that `build.sh` exists.
Why is it the case?

Comment: Where is the code retrieval in the pipeline code?

Comment: Jenkins will retrieve it using SCM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`build.sh` was not found because it had an invalid character in the shell. I created the file on windows (which has different line endings than linux), that is why I'm getting the error message. So I just made sure the line endings are correct. Linux compatible line endings. `LF` and not `CR` nor `CRLF`. In other words: `\n` and not `\r` nor `\r\n`.

Here is an example to reproduce the issue in a container:

```
docker run --rm -it bash
bash-5.1# printf '#!/bin/sh\r\n' > /build.sh
bash-5.1# ./build.sh
bash: ./build.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
bash-5.1# /bin/sh -c ./build.sh
/bin/sh: ./build.sh: not found
```

So to fix this, I ran this command `sed -i 's/\r//' build.sh` which removes `\r` from `build.sh` if present.